# Log4J2 is not creating log files in JBOSS 7.2.8 in multi JVM, multi app setup, however LOG4J did

Tags: logging, jboss, log4j, log4j2

The Log4J 1.2.17 had been working correctly. Once switched to Log4J2, the logging works on local JBOSS 7.1 server (laptop), creating logs as it should. Once deployed to multi JVM/multi application environment, logging seems to initialize, but logs are not populated. Similar setup with LOG4J 1.2.17 worked.

The setup: JBOSS 7.2.8 has 3 JVMS, each runs its own application. Each application has its own Log4J version.

My application has log4j2 jars located within the war library:

```
MyAppWeb/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.17.1.jar
MyAppWeb/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-core-2.17.1.jar 
MyAppWeb/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.1.jar 
MyAppWeb//WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
```

Log4j2.properties file under srs/ver/resources

```
name = Log4j2PropertiesConfig
 
property.filePath = /appllogs/mds
 
#appenders
appenders = mdslogappender, ftclogappender, console

#appender for mds application log
appender.mdslogappender.type = RollingFile
appender.mdslogappender.name = MDSLOGFILE
appender.mdslogappender.fileName = ${filePath}/application.log
appender.mdslogappender.filePattern = ${filename}-backup-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}.log
appender.mdslogappender.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.mdslogappender.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%X{userId}] %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.mdslogappender.policies.type = Policies
# To change log file after 20Mb size
appender.mdslogappender.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.mdslogappender.policies.size.size=20MB
appender.mdslogappender.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.mdslogappender.strategy.max = 20
 
#appender for ftc mds log 
appender.ftclogappender.type = RollingFile
appender.ftclogappender.name = FTCLOGFILE
appender.ftclogappender.fileName=${filePath}/ftcmds.log
appender.ftclogappender.filePattern = ${filename}-backup-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}.log
appender.ftclogappender.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.ftclogappender.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%X{userId}] %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.ftclogappender.policies.type = Policies
# To change log file after 20Mb size
appender.ftclogappender.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.ftclogappender.policies.size.size=20MB
appender.ftclogappender.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.ftclogappender.strategy.max = 20


# STDOUT appender
appender.console.type=Console
appender.console.name=STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%X{userId}] %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n


#loggers
loggers = mdsfilelogger, ftcfilelogger, mdsappfilelogger


#logger for mds components application 
logger.mdsfilelogger.name = com.xxx.yyy.components.mds
logger.mdsfilelogger.level = error
logger.mdsfilelogger.additivity = false
logger.mdsfilelogger.appenderRefs = mdslogappender
logger.mdsfilelogger.appenderRef.mdslogappender.ref = MDSLOGFILE

#logger for mds app log
logger.mdsappfilelogger.name = com.xxx.mds.ui
logger.mdsfimdsappfileloggerlelogger.level = error
logger.mdsappfilelogger.additivity = false
logger.mdsappfilelogger.appenderRefs = mdslogappender
logger.mdsappfilelogger.appenderRef.mdslogappender.ref = MDSLOGFILE

#logger for mds ftc log
logger.ftcfilelogger.name=com.xxx.mds.ui.ftc
logger.ftcfilelogger.level = info
logger.ftcfilelogger.additivity = false
logger.ftcfilelogger.appenderRefs = ftclogappender
logger.ftcfilelogger.appenderRef.ftclogappender.ref = FTCLOGFILE


rootLogger.level = error, MDSLOGFILE
```

**The log intantiated in Log4JInit.java class**

**** Log4JInit.java class ****

```
package com.xxx.mds.ui.config;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationSource;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Log4jInit extends HttpServlet {
    public void init() {
        System.out.println( "*** Init MDSAppWeb Log4J" );
        try {
            String prefix = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
            //PropertyConfigurator.configure(prefix+"/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties");       
            String propertiesFile = prefix+"/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.properties";  
            ConfigurationSource source = new ConfigurationSource(new FileInputStream(propertiesFile), new File(propertiesFile));
            Configurator.initialize(null, source);
            
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jInit.class).info( "*** SUCCESS Init MDSAppWeb Log4J" );    
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println( "*** FAILED Init MDSAppWeb Log4J" );
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
}
```

When server starts it registers initialization in console:

```
11:18:35,642 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 100) *** Init PBRAppWeb Log4J
```

I added the jboss-deployment-structure.xml to the war file of application to omit JBOSS logging.

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
    <exclusions>
        <module name="org.apache.logging.log4j.api" />
        <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
        <module name="org.slf4j" />
        <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
        <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
        <module name="org.jboss.logging.jul-to-slf4j-stub" />
        <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
        <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j" />
    </exclusions>
    </deployment>
    
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I also added recommended variable to JBOSS as well:

``
Add system property in JVM level that “org.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false”

Under profile logging subsystem add “add-logging-api-dependencies=false”
``

**Still - no logs are generated**

Please help.

Comment: @James R. Perkins can you help?

Comment: Where is the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` in your WAR?

Comment: It is under WebContent/WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml in the war file

Comment: Does it end up in your WAR file? You should be able to see that by `jar tf YourWar.war`.

Comment: Yes, it did. Just validated. Also, it works in local JBOSS server. Does not work in server with multi JVM. Where each JVM runs its own app

Comment: That seems very strange. Is the version on the server the same version you're running locally?

Comment: No, but I hope that should not be much important. locally - JBOSS 7.1 and multi JVM is JBOSS 7.2.8

Comment: It shouldn't, I'm just trying to figure out any differences. It should work with how you've described, so there must be some kind of environmental difference.

Comment: Thank you. I have the same feeling but I cannot pinpoint nor explain to RedHat - they simply say this is my application issue.